# Differential equation with deviating argument

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Does exist a general solution for this kind of differential equations?
$$y'(x)=-x\space y(x-2)$$

Comment: Do you mean $y' = -x(x -2) y = (2x - x^2)y$ or $y' = -x y(x - 2)$, where $y(x-2)$ is the function $y$ evaluated at $x -2$?  Because it makes a ***big*** difference!  Cheers!

Comment: y(x-2) is the function evaluated at (x-2), otherwise it is a simple differential equation

Comment: Agreed.  Thanks.

Comment: Also, what about an initial and/or boundary condition?

Comment: I added the "differential equations" tag.

Comment: This is a "delay differential equation."  I don't think I've ever handled one, but there is a wiki page:   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delay_differential_equation

Comment: In general, analysis of DDE is not straightforward. If you have $y(t)$ defined from [-2, 0] you can reduce the problem to an ODE for a defined range $[0, 2]$. Simply define $g_0(t) = y(t-2)$ over the range $[0, 2]$. Then the equation becomes $y' = -x g_0(t)$ which is integrable. You can imagine, then, "marching" along the $t$ axis in increments of 2 using previous solutions as new $g_n(t) = y(t)$ for $t$ in the range $[2n, 2n+2]$.

Comment: I think integral transform techniques may work, like the Laplace transform, but the solution will be "complicated".